# Google Analytics - Viewing total traffic across all accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client with 20+ GA accounts within their instance, and so far I have not been able to figure out an easy method of reporting the **total, global** raw number of sessions across all the accounts. The only method I can think of, so far, is to click through every single account and then record that number.

I tried importing that data into Data Studio, but it allows you to pull data from one GA account at a time.

I realize some of them would be duplicate users, but we are trying to price out a number of tech solutions for the client -- which requires the total monthly session average across all accounts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the GA Google Sheets add-on? You can configure and run a number of reports across different GA accounts and Properties. This would then allow you to use the report data from the various generated reports within the same (or different workbook) for end calculations.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in standard/free Google Analytics. You would have to literally get the data from all of your properties' raw data view in all your accounts for the same audience and time frame, and add it up - basically what you're forced to do currently.

In GA360, which is an expensive enterprise version, you can use [roll-up reporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6033415). This feature won't be exactly what you want, because it doesn't roll up on account level, only on property level, so if you don't already have it, it won't be worth the money. However, if you do, it will at least aggregate the numbers from all properties in a single account, which will save you some steps.

Then, there are third party vendors. I don't use any of them, as I have never had a business need to do so, so I can't recommend or endorse any, nor advise against any of them. For example, there's a company called DashThis and it [seems to offer a solution](https://dashthis.com/support/consolidate-aggregate-data-from-many-google-analytics-accounts-profiles/). Again, this is not an endorsement, it's just a starting point for your research. There may be other vendors offering competitive solutions that are better (or worse).

Answer (score 2):

1. Google Sheets, Google Analytics Add-in - use the wizard to create the query you want for one View ID and run the query. You now have a Report Configuration sheet. Make a copy of the first column (B) for each View ID. Run the Add-in again and you'll get a sheet of results for each View ID. In a blank sheet do the maths you want to work out the average. Check each sheet to find out if there has been 'sampling'.

Or:

2. Using Python or R, write some code to query the Google Analytics API for each View ID's sessions (I imagine you could have a Python list or R vector of View IDs, a function to query the API and a loop to call the function for each ID), with no sampling. Then write some code to do the maths on the results.

If you haven't done any of this before, the first method is more manual labour but much easier in terms of learning curve (basically a spreadsheet).